# Where to define a Meteor helper function that I can reuse in template helpers

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-helper

For example, I have a function to get params from the URL. Where should I define it, so that I can use this function in my template helpers repeatedly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the function in a `lib` folder under `client`. `lib` is loaded before files in `client`, so it will be accessible from all files in `client`. However, if you have files in subdirectories under `client`, `lib` will be loaded *after* them, so the helper won't be accessible from those deeper nested files.

You may want to learn more about [Structuring your app](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp).

The best strategy to control load order is to [organize *all* your code in packages](http://meteor.redandivory.com/#/6) - the ultimate in modularity and reusability. Your helper function should be defined in a package that will be used throughout the app.

See this excellent [presentation on building large Meteor apps](http://meteor.redandivory.com/).

Comment: I define the function in `client/lib/helpers.js`.But the Template.post.helpers can't find the function.

Comment: Where is `Template.post.helpers`?

Comment: `client/views/posts/post.js`

Comment: That explains it - deeper directories in client (views/posts) are loaded before higher-level ones (lib). Try creating a global MyApp object and defining the helper there.

Comment: @DanDascalescu does this explain why I have [issues with helpers inside templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586057/meteor-helpers-not-available-in-angular-app)?