# Meteor helpers not available in Angular template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, meteor-helper

I am learning [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) and I'm trying to add internationalization support with the `tap:18n` package. Unfortunately, the template helper function `_` is not availble inside Angular modules. For example

```
<div>{{_ "foo"}}</div>
```

works, but does not when using it inside a module template :

#### > index.html

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-include="'foo.ng.html'">
```

#### > foo.ng.html

```
<div ng-app="bar">
  <div>{{_ "bar"}}</div>
</div>
```

**note:** `app` is declared inside `foo.js` as `angular.module('app', ['angular-meteor']);`, in the project root level.

Is it possible to make helpers available inside Angular modules?

(note: see referenced [issue](https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n/issues/96).)

### ** Edit **

Same thing happens when trying to render [package templates](https://atmospherejs.com/ian/accounts-ui-bootstrap-3) inside another template :

#### > index.html

```
<section ng-app="users"
         ng-include="'users/usersession.ng.html'">
</section>
```

#### > users/usersession.ng.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  {{> loginButtons}} <!-- here -->
</ul>
```

Then I get `Syntax Error: Token '>' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression [> loginButtons] starting at [> loginButtons]`.

**Note:** the module `users` is defined and everything works fine without the `{{> loginButtons}}` expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [meteor templates inside angular](http://angular-meteor.com/api/meteor-include). Try something like:

```
<meteor-include src="myTemplate"></meteor-include>
```

Your template would be something like:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    <div>{{_ "foo"}}</div>
</template>
```

Remember when naming .html files, the angular templates will be name.ng.html and the meteor templates will just be name.html

Comment: So.... I should never use `ng-include`, then? Because all my templates will make use of helpers. The question I am having with this answer is : "If meteor templates are available inside an Angular template, then why aren't helpers available, too???" This makes no sense to me.

Comment: Because Uri doesn't want to/have time to add all the helpers to angular-meteor probably. The faster way was to add in meteor-include so you could add in all the meteor templates you need. I'm building an entire content management system including a forum and I only have one template I'm using for meteors markdown. I put that into an angular directive so I only have to write angular when I need to use it.

Comment: Some of these helpers are third-party package helpers (like `tap:i18n`'s `_` helper) and some are other packages' templates that require the `>` helper. Bottom line is, while you offer *a* solution to resolve this, this is not "acceptable" to me, and does not really explain why these helpers are not available inside Angular includes.

Comment: They're not available in angular includes because angular is processing it and not Blaze. Angular doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: So, in short, Blaze and Angular have similar view engine syntax; where both have independent helpers? I fairly new to both world and this is quite confusing.

Comment: My apologies, yes, blaze & meteor are completely separate from Angular.

Comment: It might be interesting to add some kind of way to use Blaze helpers inside Angular.  Do you think about a possible solution?  or maybe just how would you want the API to look?

Comment: Helper functions were easier than I thought, at least so far in testing. In app.run I did `$rootScope.uiHelpers = UI._globalHelpers;` and now in my template I can use for instance `<any ng-show="$root.uiHelpers.isInRole('admin')">` with the alanning:meteor-roles template helper function